# PHP Finding Unique Data in A CSV column

Tags: php

I am trying to gather all of the unique items in the 'Make' columnn of a csv.  Basically, its all the Makes in a list of towed cars.  There is a 'Make' Field in the CSV.

I have attempted the following solution:

```
$towFileString = file_get_contents("the link would go here");
file_put_contents('tow-data.csv', $towFileString);

$csvArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file('tow-data.csv'));

//echo count($csvArray);

$allMakes = array_column($csvArray, 'Make');
$uniqueMakes = array_unique($allMakes);

echo count($uniqueMakes);
```

I can see that $csvArray is being created and populated (it gathers thousands of items) but when i try to echo the count for $uniqueMakes I get 0.

Where did I stray here?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php what does that return?

Comment: How does `str_getcsv` associate column names with array indexes?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$csv =<<<CSV
manufacturer,model
ford,escort
delorean,dmc-12
ford,capri
vw,beetle
CSV;

$csv     = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n",$csv));
$headers = array_shift($csv);

$manufacturer_idx = array_search('manufacturer', $headers);
$manufacturers    = [];
foreach($csv as $v) {
    $manufacturers[] = $v[$manufacturer_idx];
}

$manufacturers = array_unique($manufacturers);
sort($manufacturers);
var_export($manufacturers);
```

Output:

```
array (
0 => 'delorean',
1 => 'ford',
2 => 'vw',
)
```

Comment: Thank you.  The csv I am using is much more complex than your example and that is the problem I am having.  All the examples I can find are relatively simple and I'm having difficulty extrapolating from them. It is not just a comma delimited list of makes.  The first row consists of headers like 'Make', 'Model', 'License', etc. I need to pick out all the data under the particular header, Make, and eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @DeweyBanks I've added a first row of headers to my example.  It's just a case of finding the correct associated column/index is it not?